# Aligning buttons with box component

Tags: java, swing, alignment, boxlayout

So I want to create something like this:

[image]

Finally I'm making some progress, but I'm confused as to why my buttons aren't aligning to the centre and as to why it isn't creating a gap between them.

Here's my code:

```
canvas.setLayout(new BoxLayout(canvas, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

//buttons
final JButton btn1 = new JButton(play);
btn1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
btn1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btn1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
btn1.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
        if (model.isRollover())
            btn1.setRolloverIcon(playro);
    }
});
final JButton btn2 = new JButton(instructions);
btn2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
btn2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btn2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
btn2.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
        if (model.isRollover())
            btn2.setRolloverIcon(instructionsro);
    }
});     

canvas.add(btn1);
canvas.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
canvas.add(btn2);
```

This is what it creates:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Fixed the issue with the gap between the buttons. I realised I wasn't adding it to the canvas. Still confused with the alignment issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BoxLayout` is not the best layout you should use for that task. I would recommend `BorderLayout` in conjunction with `FlowLayout`. So, something like this:

```
canvas.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(); // Panel where you can
// place those buttons (by default,
// FlowLayout has been set on it)
bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 30, 0));
canvas.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
bottomPanel.add(btn1);
bottomPanel.add(btn2);
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work pretty well. I'm just wondering though; how can I move the JPanel up slightly?

Comment: What do you mean by move? Also, consider to accept answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Consider using `PAGE_END` over `SOUTH`, since Java is encouraging the use of the former over the latter since `1.4` :-)

Comment: Oh yes I get it. You can do that by determining gap. But in that case you will have to set `FlowLayout` for your `bottomPanel` manualy : `bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));` P.S. Thanks for that tip @nIcEcOw.

Comment: By move, I mean how do I position the buttons like in the image I provided? Currently they almost touch the bottom and I want to position them slightly higher. Manually setting FlowLayout only sets the horizontal gaps.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I meant the vertical gap, however I've figured it out. I could set it in the BorderLayout constructor.

Comment: Doh! I made a mistake. Use `BorderFactory` instead: `bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 30, 10));` 3rd argument determines spacing from bottom.